# How do I find all markers/features within a given radius of any arbitrary point and store the lat/lng of said markers?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

Given a point, say [-75.343, 39.984], how do I go about finding all features/markers within a 5km radius of it? I'm utilizing turf.js so I'll be using their `circle()` function to generate the circle about the point.

Would this work?

```
const center = [-75.343, 39.984];
const radius = 5;
const options = {steps: 10, units: 'kilometers', properties: {foo: 'bar'}};
const circle = turf.circle(center, radius, options);
}

const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(
circle,
{ filter:  {["within", circle] : true} }
);
```

I'm hoping to find all features within the circle and be able to store them in an array or in a database for further processing like accessing the feature's lat/lng, etc.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Using `queryRenderedFeatures` you will be able to get the features that are actually in the viewport (visible). In case your source data is GeoJSON, you can use `querySourceFeatures`, so it will look to all your source features:

```
const filteredFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures('routes', {
  filter: ['within', circle]
});
```